# IncompatileClassChangeError when starting Play 2.1.1 server?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I written a Play/Java/Akka project and when I started the Play server, I faced the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps, but interface was expected
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$.main(NettyServer.scala:257)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer.main(NettyServer.scala)
```

It's with Play 2.1.1 + Java 1.7.0_45 and Scala 2.10.0

Any idea on which version is wrong here?

Comment: It looks like you are using a version of Play that has been built against a different version of Scala. I'm not sure how that happened since normally the Scala version is determined automatically. Did you set `scalaVersion` yourself in your build file?

Comment: Following up @RobinGreen's comment - what's your build configuration - `build.sbt`/`project/*.scala`? How do you start your project? Could you publish a sample that reproduces the error on GitHub?